# Violation of primary key constraint-- firebird SQL

Tags: sql, database, firebird, firebird2.5

I'm getting an error

> Violation of PRIMARY or UNIQUE KEY constraint

when I try to run this `insert` statement (from a C# interface):

```
INSERT INTO descript (PROPID, OBJID, NAME, CLASSID, LASTUPDATE,
                      HISTORY, VIVDRULE, CAPTION, PROMPT, DESCRIPTION)
VALUES (@PROPID, //110
        @OBJID,  //2109900055
        @NAME,  //Custom10
        @CLASSID,  //3
        @LASTUPDATE,  //4/29/2016
        @HISTORY,  // ''
        @VIVDRULE,  //1
        @CAPTION,  //test10
        @PROMPT,  //yo
        @DESCRIPTION  // ''
)
```

The specific error is:

> Violation of PRIMARY or UNIQUE KEY constraint "DESCRIPTOR$OBJID" on table "DESCRIPT"*.

`OBJID` is the primary key for that table.

However, if I run

```
select * 
from descript 
where objid = 2109900055
```

no rows are returned, so I know that there isn't actually a duplicate.

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16520884/sql-primary-key-constraint-although-record-does-not-exist), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25891822/violation-of-primary-key-constraint-query), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796009/violation-of-primary-key-constraint), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103016/violation-of-primary-key-constraint-error-sql), but none of them seem to have an applicable solution, or at least, not one that works.  I'm also using Firebird SQL, if that makes a difference.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Why insert into the primary key anyway?

Comment: @Mihai I have to.  This is part of a very large and complicated project/database, and none of our primary keys can auto-increment.  So they have to be set in the insert.

Comment: Are multiple inserts happening by any chance? Also, datatype is integer?

Comment: @I_am_Batman  No.  Only the one insert.

Comment: What happens if you use `where objid+0 = 2109900055`. There are cases where an entry is in the table, but not in the index; using `+0` will ignore the index for the lookup. Another possibility is that you have a limbo transaction that also inserted this value. Limbo transactions are prepared, but not yet committed.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel using `objid+0 = 2109900055` makes no difference-- no rows are returned.  It does not seem to be a limbo transaction.

Comment: Have you tried creating a backup and restoring the database?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel No, but that's my next step.  Another similar question said that their issues were due to corruption, so...

Answer (score 0):

Check the data type for OBJID and its limitations. I suspect with that large of a number you are exceeding the max size of the data type.

Comment: If it is integer, no it isn't.

Comment: It is an integer, so I'm not too big yet.